# C/C++. input line of numbers

Tags: c++, c, io, scanf, cin

Need to input data about multiple structure variables (format - 3 groups of 2 numbers in one line). Used "for" and custom input function (also it calculates some parameters). Now tryed to use "std::cin" :

```
typedef struct {
  short width;
  short height;
  short left;
  short top;

  int S;
  short orientation;
} Rectangle;

bool input_rectangle(Rectangle* rect) {
  short width;
  short height;

  std::cin >> width >> height;

  (*rect).width  = width;
  (*rect).height = height;
  (*rect).S      = width * height;

  (*rect).top  = 0;
  (*rect).left = 0;

  if(width>height) {
    (*rect).orientation = HORIZONTAL;
  }
  else {
    (*rect).orientation = VERTICAL;
  }

  return width!=0 || height!=0;
}

int main() {
  Rectangle* rectangles = new Rectangle[RECTANGLES_COUNT];
  ...
  while(1) {
    ...
    for(int i=0;i<RECTANGLES_COUNT;i++) {
      will_continue = will_continue || input_rectangle(&rectangles[i]);
    }
    if(!will_continue) {
      break;
    }
    else {
      int S = calculate(rectangles);
    }
    ... 
  }
}
```

It give wrong result. Tryed to add debug output to "calculate" :

```
for(int i=0;i<RECTANGLES_COUNT;i++)
  std::cout << rectangles[i].width << " x " << rectangles[i].height << " = " << rectangles[i].S << "\n";
```

Example of result.

```
4 16 6 6 5 10 #my input
4 x 16 = 64   #right
0 x 0 = 0     #??? Must be 6 x 6  = 36
0 x 0 = 0     
646 x 6 = 36
0 x 0 = 0
0 x 0 = 0
365 x 10 = 50
0 x 0 = 0
0 x 0 = 0
```

How can I improve it? Also I tryed to use `scanf("%hd %hd", &width, &height);` (may ise pure C in this task), but it give same result.

Used g++ compiler / (gcc for pure C version)

Comment: Have you used a debugger to step through your code? Doing so, you can pause on a specific line and examine what each variable holds.

Comment: Also, [your program works for me](http://ideone.com/qf9l2h).

Comment: All getted by it - that at `std::cin >> width >> height`, at seconf time I have 0,0, as well as my input/output example.`std::cin >> width >> height >> temp;`temp readed correctly,

Comment: @AnishRamaswamy Oh, I'm so glad to see that. I don't know C++ really, but it looked like it should just work.

Comment: Well clearly some other code is interfering. As you can plainly see with the [example I showed you earlier](http://ideone.com/qf9l2h), your code that deals with the input works. What would be really helpful is if you could write up a [small program](http://www.sscce.org/) that reproduces the issue you complain of.

Comment: Do you want answer in C or C++?  This is one area where there is a difference between the two languages.

Comment: You should remove the "c" tag, as `cin` and extraction operators are not defined in the C language.

Answer (score 0):

From your debug output code, I'm gathering that for your test purposes RECTANGLES_COUNT is actually defined to 3.
Also, since it is able to perform any kind of computations, and given that the || operator is subject to lazy-evaluation, you must be initializing `will_continue` to `false`.

What's happening is when your first input (i=0) is in fact valid (i.e. width or height is not 0), `will_continue` gets set `true`. Then since `true ||` *anything* must be true, input_rectangle is no longer called (lazy-evaluation) for `i=1,2,...` So only `rectangle[0]` gets set in that loop. When you latter call your debug output in `calculate`, you show all 3 rectangles' width/height/S including 2 that have presumably been initialized to 0 (and remain to their initial value).

I'm guessing (though not shown) that `int S = calculate(rectangles)` might in fact assigns the sum of `rectangle[i].S` (which happens to be equal to `rectangle[0].S`, since the others are 0s) to `S` which you are then printing. That would explain the lines containing 646 (64 followed by 6 x 6) and 365 (36 followed by 5 x 5).

I'm guessing what you wanted was probably more along the lines of:

```
...
while(1) {
  ...
  bool will_continue = false;
  for(int i=0;i<RECTANGLES_COUNT;i++) {
    will_continue = input_rectangle(&rectangles[i]);
    if (!will_continue) {
      break;
    }
  }
  if(!will_continue) {
    break;
  }
  else {
    int S = calculate(rectangles);
  }
  ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return width!=0 || height!=0;
```

should be

```
return width!=0 && height!=0;
```